# How to Implement a Passwordless authentication to Embedded SFTP with Apache MINA SSHD

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I'm trying to implement a multi user password-less Embedded SFTP with Apache MINA SSHD with help of this example [Here](https://programmingtechie.com/2019/08/18/how-to-implement-an-sftp-server-in-java-spring-boot-using-apache-mina-sshd-part-2-using-public-key-authentication/). But When I'm trying to connect to the server, it always demands a password.

[Password Authentication Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLIkb.png)

```java
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setHost("localhost");
        sshd.setPort(2222);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider());
        sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(
                (username, password, session) -> username.equals("test") && password.equals("password"));
        Path keys = Paths.get(".ssh/authorized_keys");
        if (keys.toFile().exists()) {
            sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(new AuthorizedKeysAuthenticator(keys));
            log.info("File exists....");
        }
        sshd.start();
        log.info("SFTP server started");
```

I've put the authorized_keys (public key file) inside .ssh folder within the project.

[ssh folder for sftp server project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6KBs.png)

Comment: Hai, No one has that time to look into external links and check. Please post your code where your are going wrong or what you implemented so for and what have you tried so for. So that any one can help you.

Comment: Hi, I've modified the post as suggested, I wish that will help anyone to get a clear idea about the problem.

Comment: @MounirBelhniyene I am the author of the blog post you mentioned.

If you are following the steps provided in the blog post, I guess the first thing I would look into is the authorized_keys file may be the contents of the file are not copied correctly.

Try to re-generate the public key and copy the contents to the target file.

The code you posted is working fine.

Also, use the following command to see the verbose output from the sftp command to understand the problem a bit more.

sftp -vvv -oPort=2222 test@localhost